# Elasticsearch Query's Result (PHP)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Given the document's structure

```
{
    "id":""
    "field1":""
    "field2":""
    "field3":""
    "field4":""
 }
```

when querying

```
require 'composer/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Elasticsearch\Client(['hosts' => ['127.0.0.1:9200']]);

$value = $_POST['q'];

$query = $client->search(['body' => ['query' => ['bool' => ['should' => [
                    ['match' => ['title' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field1' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field2' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field3' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field4' => $value]]
                    ]]]]]);

if ($query['hits']['total'] >= 1) {
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
}
```

$results returns all the fields.

How can I make $results returns only id, field1 and field 4 searching anyway through all the document's fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use [`_source` filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) in your query like this

```
$query = $client->search(['body' => ['_source' => ['id', 'field1', 'field4'],
              'query' => ['bool' => ['should' => [
                    ['match' => ['title' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field1' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field2' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field3' => $value]],
                    ['match' => ['field4' => $value]]
                    ]]]]]);
```

Comment: This may be my setup, but source filtering caused my query times to go from 7ms-100ms to 100ms-400ms. I ended up manually filtering with a loop in php which added 10-50ms in time (machine time, not cpu time).

Comment: @Chris Well, that's weird, that might indeed depend on many factors, such as mapping size, number of fields, number of docs, etc. Feel free to ask another specific question and reference this one if you want to dig deeper

Comment: I thought it weird as well,It's probably how I'm using it as I only started with Elastic search three days ago.